# GCP MQL query. Manipulate query to remove resource.location from legend / name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, dashboard, metrics, mql

I've created a widget to display JAVA memory usage.

As legend I see :
[image]

Is there any chance to hide for example resource.location from the name?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Filters and Group by to reduce data returned for a metric type and [combine multiple time series](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/aggregation?&_ga=2.61489132.-1179841927.1676417515#reduction-intro) by selecting labels and a group functioning.

To configure a chart on a custom dashboard to display time-series data collected by your project, see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/selecting-aggregating-metrics).

See also [Monitoring filters](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters#time-series-filter).

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve this issue with
```
group_by [resource.pod_name,metric.id,metric.area], [value_max_mean: mean(value.max)]
```